# android:how to ensure only one process(of a remote-service) running even all APPs integrated this service in the apk

Tags: android, service, share

1.I'm implementing a SDK using android remote service.
2.in order to distribute this SDK,I'd like that as many APPs integrate my SDK as it could be.
3.in order to save system resources, I'd like only one process of the remote service running in background to support all APPs who need the remote-service.

is there any way to achieve this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some resource locking mechanism. If you're already handling a call from app A, and app B wants the same call, return an error code that isn't fatal, rather tells the app to try back at another time. Or you could create a queue with a callback to app B that fires when app A is done.